# No keyboard input in Unity3D game builds

Tags: keyboard, registry, unity-game-engine, directinput

I'm using Unity3D and I'm having issues with the keyboard when I 'build' the project.

When I run the game within the Unity Editor, the input works fine. However, when I build the project and test it, I have no directional input whatsoever. The mouse works fine, the game registers keystrokes (the Esc key works), but the player won't move.

I'm using `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")`

I researched the issue on the web, but I'm still stucked. The only solution I found (in various links) mentions a problem with DirectInput and states that you should remove the key "Input" from `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Unity\Player]`, in the Windows registry, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Has anybody else fought this problem? Any working solutions? Am I doing the registry trick wrong?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you take the build and run it on a different machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was troubling me.

`Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` were fine the whole time. Somehow, there was some code in the script that in the Editor worked just fine, but when running as standalone gave me a calculation equal to 0 (it depends on the Delta Time, so I assume that the Delta Time when running compiled is much smaller than when running in the Unity Editor) and thus the character didn't move at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Input Manager in Edit->Project Settings-> Input. Have you tried using GetAxis instead of GetAxisRaw? I also suggest using, eg: Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) and etc.

Comment: I tried both GetAxis and GetAxisRaw.

I was planning of using the approach you suggest, using GetKey, if I can't solve this issue.